# How to exit iterminal in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I would like to start emacs with proxychains with a bash script in a terminal and then exit the terminal. But the code

```
(proxychains emacs &)
exit 0
```

dosen't exit the terminal. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this test script.

**t.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
echo bye bye
sleep 5
pid=$( ps -f | grep "bash" | grep -v grep )
kill -HUP $pid
```

OK, open a new command line terminal window. From that window, execute the bash script just created (assume yhou named it "t.sh" as above).

```
bash t.sh
```

You should see that command line window disappear after 10 seconds, as the shell script commits suicide by killing the bash process that launched it.

I think there may have been an easier way to do this, but I don't remember what it was.

At any rate, from your description, I assume this is what you're looking to accomplish.

**EDIT:**

I actually don't like the solution above. It seems to me that what you probably really want to do is run the bash script in the background and use "nohup" so that you can log off.

What happens then is that the process will continue running until completed, then go away, essentially what I think you're asking for.

You can do that as so:

**t1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am doing my thing then leaving" > /tmp/t1.log
sleep 10
exit 0
```

Then from command line:

```
nohup bash t1.sh &
```

then just go ahead and log off.

Come back 15 seconds later, you should have a file, "/tmp/t1.log", with your output.

Comment: However the terminal is not closed.